# Logstash grok config error - while parsing file name

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I am new to logstash and grok and I am trying to parse AWS ECS logs in an S3 bucket in the following format -

File Name - `my-logs-s3-bucket/3d265ee3-d2ee-4029-a3d9-fd2255d69b92/ecs-fargate-container-8ff0e472-c76f-4f61-a363-64c2b80aa842/000000.gz`

Sample Lines -

```
2019-05-09T16:16:16.983Z   JBoss Bootstrap Environment
2019-05-09T16:16:16.983Z   JBOSS_HOME: /app/jboss
2019-05-09T16:16:16.983Z   JAVA_OPTS:  -server -XX:+UseCompressedOops  -Djboss.server.log.dir=/var/log/jboss -Xms128m -Xmx4096m
```

And logstash.conf

```
input {
  s3 {
    region => "us-east-1"
    bucket => "my-logs-s3-bucket"
    interval => "7200"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}"]
  }
  date {
    match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
  }
  mutate {
    remove_field => ["tstamp"]
    add_field => {
      "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}"
    }
    ######### NEED HELP HERE - START #########
    #grok {
    #  match => [ "file", "ecs-fargate-container-%{DATA:containerlogname}"]
    #}
    ######### NEED HELP HERE - END #########
  }
}

output {
 stdout { codec => rubydebug {
    #metadata => true
  }
 }
}
```

I am able to see all the logs parsed and the file name extracted when I run logstash using the above configuration and the file name from the output looks like below -

`"file" => "myapp-logs/3d265ee3-d2ee-4029-a3d9-fd2255d69b92/ecs-fargate-container-8ff0e472-c76f-4f61-a363-64c2b80aa842/000000.gz",`

I am trying to use grok to extract the file name as either `ecs-fargate-container-8ff0e472-c76f-4f61-a363-64c2b80aa842` or `8ff0e472-c76f-4f61-a363-64c2b80aa842` by uncommenting grok config lines between `#NEED HELP HERE - START` and ending with the below error -

`Expected one of #, => at line 21, column 10 (byte 536) after filter {\n  grok {\n    match => [\"message\", \"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}\"]\n  }\n  date {\n    match => [\"tstamp\", \"ISO8601\"]\n  }\n  mutate {\n    #remove_field => [\"tstamp\"]\n    add_field => {\n      \"file\" => \"%{[@metadata][s3][key]}\"\n    }\n    grok ", :`

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `grok` filter was inside the `mutate` filter, try the following.

```
filter {
    grok {
        match => ["message", "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:tstamp}"]
    }
    date {
        match => ["tstamp", "ISO8601"]
    }
    mutate {
        remove_field => ["tstamp"]
        add_field => { "file" => "%{[@metadata][s3][key]}" }
    }
    grok {
        match => [ "file", "ecs-fargate-container-%{DATA:containerlogname}"]
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. I too figured out the answer to this after posting the question, but SO does not allow me to add the answer for a day or something!